# Heroku & Rails -- Subsequent AJAX Request Stalls following AJAX Delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku

To preface, my AJAX requests seem to work perfectly fine in my local environment. When I push the files to Heroku, my get/patch AJAX requests seem to also work fine, albeit slightly slowly.

When I make a delete request to my Rails server through AJAX however, the subsequent AJAX request made never finishes pending. Checking the Heroku server logs, the server does in fact receive a request and it returns content, but for some reason, the AJAX request never seems to acknowledge that it's finished.

If I make yet another AJAX request however, it seems to work fine once again, unless I followed up with a delete request to a resource which already received a delete request but was stuck in pending. In that case, every subsequent request is just stuck.

Edit: Things seem to run fine when using a Safari browser, but not Chrome or Firefox. Going to eat and then test on a different laptop.

[image: Chrome Network Tool]

[image: Chrome Network Tool #2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to my own installed applications. In particular, Sophos Anti-Virus was responsible. Disabling the web protection features seemed to have done the trick.